# How can I speed up this sql server query?

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, optimization

```
-- Holds last 30 valdates
create table #valdates(
    date int
)
insert into #valdates
   select distinct top (30) valuation_date 
   from tbsm.tbl_key_rates_summary 
   where valuation_date <= 20150529 
   order by valuation_date desc 

select 
    sum(fv_change), sc_group, valuation_date  
from
    (select * 
     from tbsm.tbl_security_scorecards_summary 
     where valuation_date in (select date from #valdates)) as fact
join 
    (select * 
     from tbsm.tbl_security_classification 
     where sc_book = 'UC' ) as dim on fact.classification_id = dim.classification_id
group by 
    valuation_date, sc_group

drop table #valdates
```

This query takes around 40 seconds to return because the fact table has almost 13 million rows.. Can I do anything about this?

Comment: Just a side note, if you are only holding 30 values I would create a temp table in memory -->DECLARE TABLE @valdates{...}. It is all in memory and you do not need to worry about dropping it later, it is automatically dropped when the stored procedure or sql command loses scope.

Comment: Table variables are not "all in memory", they are stored in tempdb like temporary tables too, and can cause even bigger problems due to missing statistics / estimated row count of 1. Normal temporary tables are dropped too when the procedure ends.

Comment: We actually improved performance greatly when switching the declare @tmp tables to create #tmp table. The bigger the data that the temp table would hold, the greater the performance increase. I will give your tip a try tho, thanks.

Comment: @Allen, you should include at least some idea about what the tables and indexes are and possibly also query plan for this select. My guess is that you have index for valuation_date, but does it contain fv_change too, or are there key lookups done to find that and / or classification_id?

Comment: @Jamez, The fact table contains fv_change, valuation_date. The dim table contains sc_book, sc_group. We filter by sc_book and aggregate by sc_group. Classification ID joins the two tables. Unfortunately the indexes for both tables are basically bogus. Also, valuation_date is not indexed :(

Comment: @jamesz - I'll stand by what I said, if the amount of data is going to be small and used to filter a larger query then I would use a Table Variable as opposed to a Temp Table. I believe that a Table Variable is primary a memory resident; only stored in TempDB if it grows large. I find that Table Variables out perform Temp Tables with small datasets.

Comment: valuation_date is in both your group and select clause. I bet a 'non-clustered' index on valuation_date, fact.classification_id and dim.classification_id would greatly increase the speed of your query.

Comment: @Irb great, I was thinking of someting like this already!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that there's no proper index that supports the fetch, that's probably the easiest (or only) option to really improve the performance. Most likely index like this would improve the situation a lot:

```
create index idx_security_scorecards_summary_1 on 
tbl_security_scorecards_summary (valuation_date, classification_id) 
include (fv_change)
```

Everything depends of course on how good the selectivity of the valuation_date and classification_id fields are (=how big portion of the table needs to be fetched) and might work better with the fields in opposite order. The field fv_change is in the include section so that it's included in the index structure so there's no need to fetch it from the base table.

Include fields help if the SQL has to fetch a lot of rows from the table. If the amount of rows that this touches is small, then it might not help at all. Like always in indexing, this of course slows down the inserts / updates, and is optimized for this case only and you should of course look at the bigger picture too.

The select is written in a little bit strange way, not sure if that makes any difference, but you could also try the normal way to do this:

```
select 
    sum(fact.c), dim.sc_group, fact.valuation_date  
from
    tbsm.tbl_security_scorecards_summary fact
    join tbsm.tbl_security_classification dim
        on fact.classification_id = dim.classification_id
where 
    fact.valuation_date in (select date from #valdates) and
    dim.sc_book = 'UC'
group by 
    fact.valuation_date, 
    dim.sc_group
```

Looking at "statistics io" output should give you a good idea which table is causing the slowness, and looking at query plan to see if there's any strange operators might help to understand the situation better.

Comment: @Jamez, Wow holy crap, my query went from 40+ seconds to 2 seconds after I created the index. Will this affect writing performance? In the future, will we need to re-index regularly or will newly inserted records be auto indexed? Also, what exactly did I create when I executed the 'create index' script? Is this different from a clustered/nonclustered index?

Comment: @Allen There is a small price for each insert (+ possible for update) for every index, so you'll have to check how that behaves. New records will be automatically added, but all indexes do require some maintenance. If you're the (accidential) DBA, you should look into Ola's scripts: https://ola.hallengren.com/